# What does "analytic" mean in the context of control system

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory

Consider LTI causal and finite-dimensional system $G$ and let $\hat{G}$ be its Laplace transform.

> We say that $\hat{G}$ is stable if it is analytic in the closed right half-plane (Re $s>0$).

What "*analytic*" means here?

I know that $\hat{G}$ is stable if doesn't have poles in RHP. Also I found wiki definition for [analytic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function). But I couldn't relate them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wikipedia definition is exactly right.

Your system is a linear time-invariant system of differential equations in finitely many variables.  The Laplace transform of such a system is a rational function, and thus is analytic except for poles.  It is stable if none of those poles are in the closed right half plane (which, BTW, is ${\text Re}(s) \ge 0$, not $>0$).